# Will I lose my League/Rank in Starcraft 2 due to inactivity?

Tags: starcraft-2

I just got promoted to diamond league. If I stop playing for a while, will I get demoted back to a lower league? If so, how lang can I stay inactive without this happening?
Also, will I get demoted, when I lose to much games?

Answer (score -3):

I found out this FAQ: http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Battle.net_Leagues#Hidden_.22Matchmaking_Rating.22_.28MMR.29

For Master, Diamond, Platinum, Gold, Silver, and Bronze leagues, you will not be demoted for inactivity. (Inactive players are demoted out of Grandmaster league.)

Comment: This is not true.  If you read at the bottom of the document, and you don't play for a season your MMR gets completely reset.  I can also confirm this is true.  I went from Master and due to inactivity got placed in gold or plat from my placments.  I can't remember which one.